# Неоднократный — несовершенный вид?

Tags: видовые-пары

Сразили сейчас вопросом. "Ткнуть" - это соврешенный вид, однократный.
Аналогично "прыгнуть", "стукнуть" и проч. Но ***надо выразить законченное неоднократное действие***. Что-то вроде "оттыкал(ся)". Но это совсем другое значение.
***И вообще, есть ли в русском вообще грамматическое средство для выражения таких действий?*** Отпрылал(ся)? Отстрелял(ся)?

И еще, интуитивно кажется, что тут есть какая-то связь с глаголами повторяющегося действия (бежать – бегать, брести – бродить, везти – возить, вести – водить, гнать – гонять, ехать – ездить, идти – ходить, катить – катать, лезть – лазить, лететь – летать, нести – носить, плыть – плавать, ползти – ползать, тащить – таскать и условно быть-бывать). Или это моя фантазия?

Кстати, куда девается Ы в Тыкать-ткунуть?

ЗЫ Вообще я всегда сомневался в универсальности идеи существования одной видовой пары... Для бесприставочных глаголов как-то не всегда получается найти точную видовую пару среди приставочных...

**[@Fuchoin Kazuki](/users/3/fuchoin-kazuki), мне не нравится ваш вариант заголовка. Тире там не должно быть ни в каком понимании. Совсем другой смысл.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Практически все примеры с глаголами повторяющегося действия - это глаголы движения. Иностранцам они преподаются как особая группа глаголов, причем отводится на эту тему довольно много часов. Выделение этих глаголов в особую группу объясняется как близостью их лексических значений, так и общими словообразовательными и грамматическими свойствами, отличающими их от остальных глаголов.

14 пар глаголов **несовершенного вида**, обозначающих перемещение: *идти - ходить, бежать - бегать, ехать - ездить, лететь - летать, плыть - плавать, тащить -таскать, катить - катать, нести — носить, вести — водить, везти — возить, ползти - ползать, лезть - лазить (и лазать), брести — бродить и гнать — гонять.*

Первые члены каждой из перечисленных пар (т.н. глаголы однонаправленного движения) обозначают действие, совершаемое в одном направлении и за один приём (без перерывов), вторые члены (глаголы неоднонаправленного движения) обозначают действие, совершаемое в разных направлениях или регулярно повторяющееся, ср.: *Он идёт в лес и Он ходит по комнате, Он каждый день ходит в лес*.

В формах прош. времени глаголы неоднонаправленного движения могут обозначать действие, совершённое в двух направлениях - туда и обратно: *Он сегодня ходил в магазин*. В этих контекстах неоднонаправленные глаголы могут обозначать ту же ситуацию, что и глаголы сов. вида (ср. *Он сегодня сходил в магазин*), отличаясь от последних отсутствием обязательного указания на однократность действия.

От глаголов однонаправленного движения регулярно образуются глаголы сов. вида с приставкой по- начинательного значения (*побежать*) и с разнообразными приставками пространственных значений (*вбежать, перебежать, подбежать*). От глаголов неоднонаправленного движения образуются префиксальные глаголы сов. вида с временными и количественно-временными значениями: *забегать, побегать, пробегать, набегать, сбегать*.

Видообразование глаголов движения характеризуется след. особенностью: от префиксальных глаголов сов. вида, мотивированных глаголами *везти, вести, гнать, идти, лететь, нести,* глаголы несов. вида образуются по образцу соотношения однонаправленных и неоднонаправленных Гл.дв., ср.: *везти -возить и привезти - привозить; вести - водить и привести — приводить; гнать - гонять и пригнать - пригонять; идти — ходить и прийти -приходить; лететь — летать и прилететь - прилетать; нести - носить и принести - приносить.*

От остальных префиксальных Гл. дв. глаголы несов. вида образуются с помощью суффикса имперфективации: *прибежать - прибегать, забрести — забредать, приехать - приезжать, укатить — укатывать, влезть - влезать, приплыть — приплывать, заползти — заползать, оттащить - оттаскивать.*

Что касается пары ТЫКАТЬ - ТКНУТЬ (это не глаголы движения, здесь глагол СВ образован при помощи суффикса однократного действия -ну-), то Ы в первом слове выпадает, потому что изначально там был гласный, обозначаемый в транскрипции как Ъ (среднего ряда среднего подъема), ср.: праслав. *tъkati (по Фасмеру, ТЫКАТЬ,ТКНУТЬ имеют общее происхождение с ТКАТЬ).

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**. Два глагола, близкие по лексическому значению, объединяются в видовую пару, если различие между такими глаголами сводится лишь к разнице в указании на внутренний предел. Если же различие между глаголами осложняется добавочными лексическими значениями одного из членов такого противопоставления, то видовой парой такие два глагола не являются.

Для глагола ТЫКАТЬ видовой парой будет глагол ТКНУТЬ (одним из способов перфективации, т.е. превращения глагола НСВ в глагол СВ, является суффиксация с -НУ-). Глагол ПОТЫКАТЬ имеет в своем составе приставку ПО-, которая добавляет к общему лексическому значению глагола ТЫКАТЬ значение небольшой продолжительности действия. Следовательно, ПОТЫКАТЬ не является парным по виду для глагода ТЫКАТЬ.

Comment: olsa, спасибо конечно, но сами по себе глаголы движения мне знакомы и понятны. Что тыкать-ткунуть к ним не относится я тоже знаю. ну и остальное более или менее известно.   
Мне часто бывает трудно сформулировать вопрос,  но тут я вроде достаточно понятно сказал. Я запнулся на однократности, о кототрой как-то очень мало говорит грамматика, и на видовых парах парах, причем совсем не с иностранцами. И мне показалось (видимо - ошибочно), что может какая-то связь этой однократности с глаголами из этого списка.

Comment: Давайте я пока с**у**жу вопрос. Какой из двух глаголов _**ткнуть**_ и _**потыкать**_ является более точной видовой парой к тыкать - и почему?

Comment: >Глагол ПОТЫКАТЬ имеет в своем составе приставку ПО-, которая добавляет к общему лексическому значению глагола ТЫКАТЬ значение небольшой продолжительности действия. Следовательно, ПОТЫКАТЬ не является парным по виду для глагода ТЫКАТЬ.  

Вот это именно то, на чем я хотел вас поймать. Глагол "ткнуть" с точки зрения такой логики ещё дальше от точной видовой пары к тыкать, поскольку означает однократное действие. Не говоря уж о том, что семантика приставки "по" отнюдь не столь узкая.

Comment: Я говорю о конкретном значении приставки ПО- в глаголе ПОТЫКАТЬ, а не о значении этой приставки "вообще". Об образовании видовых пар глаголов можно прочитать в любом университетском учебнике. Я не совсем понимаю, на чем вы меня хотели поймать. Образование глаголов СВ от глаголов НСВ с помощью суффикса -НУ-, обозначающего однократное (законченное, совершенное) действие, - регулярный способ перфективации.

Comment: Так и я о конкретном значении. А "регулярый способ перфективации" - это заклинание. Я знаю, что он "регулярный", но от этого он не ставновится менее подозрительным. 

Вы проигнорировали смысл моей реплики. Почему сужение (якобы) смысла до "небольшой продолжительности действия" - препятствие для признания "потыкать" видовой парой к "тыкать", а привнесение очевидной однократности в "ткунть" - нет? Это я веду к тому, что понятие видовой пары не столь универсально, как пытаются внушить.

Comment: Второе. То с чего я начал. Есть ли в русском языке средства для выражения неоднократного долженного перфекта)? Т.е. для некоторых глаголов перфект такой однократности не несет (поел, например, поработал), почему такая разница?